# What is the name of the violin song during the first and last episode?

Tags: music, toradora

just finished bursting into tears, along with finishing the anime.
There's this one song that destroys my heart every time it plays, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

It plays in the very first few seconds of the 1st episode.
And a few times with violin in the last episode.

First episode: 00:00- approx. 01:00

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that is "Yasashisa no Ashioto", the 28th track from the "Toradora Original Soundtrack".